# Cannot connect to MongoDb client

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am not being able to connect to MongoDB.
The error i am getting is

```
 |         options.includeResultMetadata ??= false;
20:46:01 0|app    |                                       ^^^
20:46:01 0|app    | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

Node version when i am running the project is
node -v => v20.7.0

MongoDB version
mongod --version => db version v6.0.8

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "http-status": "^1.7.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.1.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.4"
  }
}
```

What am i missing

The code

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');


const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/testDatabase';

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected to the MongoDB database');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the MongoDB database:', err);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase,
  getDatabase: () => client.db(),
};
```

Comment: Search for `options.includeResultMetadata ??= false` in your codebase and change it to  `options.includeResultMetadata ?? false`.

Comment: it doesnt exists in my codebase thats the point @selfagency

Comment: If the only package you've imported is `mongodb` and this is the entirety of your code, then it sounds like there's a bug in `mongodb` you should report because it should give you a proper error when the client fails to connect and not a syntax error.

Comment: Try downgrading to a prior version of `mongodb` to see if the problem persists.

Comment: when i connect it with mongoose its working but not with mongodb client

Answer (score 0):

```js
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testDatabase";
```

Comment: Won't work sorry

Answer (score 0):

same problem, until mongo release a patch for version 6.1.0
this worked for me... (downgrading the mongodb javascript module) as @selfagency suggested

`npm uninstall mongodb`

then

`npm i mongodb@5.9.0`

other earlier versions are available

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb/v/5.9.0?activeTab=versions

you might also edit your package.json dependencies

`"mongodb": "^6.1.0",`

to say

`"mongodb": "^5.9.0",`

and reinstall you applications dependencies. depends if you are deploying or developing locally